# How do I extract information with what I have right now?

Tags: sed, conversion

I have a bunch of swfs, these swfs include links to other swfs inside them.

I use this to convert them to xml: `swf2xml Disc1.swf Disc1.swf.xml`. Then I use this to remove every single line that does not include an swf link: `sed -i '' '/swf/!d' Disk1.swf.xml`

Id like to do this with 501 different swf files, there are two challenges:

1. I have to run the command on 500 different files and specify output.
2. I have to `sed` them all

Im trying to build a script

Currently I have this

```
swf2xml Disc1.swf
swf2xml NV.swf
...
```

Comment: I apologize for not understanding the question. The script I gave initially after my first edit should do the trick for the processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for swf in *.swf; do
    xml="$swf.xml"
    swf2xml "$swf" "$xml"
    sed -i '' -n '/swf/p' "$xml"
done
```

Comment: `swf2xml "$swf" "$xml"`

`ERROR: could not open file  for reading`

Comment: is this `swf2xml`s fault or is it your script?

Comment: Do you have any swf files in your current directory?

Comment: Yep, they are all there.

Comment: do this: `for swf in *.swf; do echo "$swf"; done` -- do you see the expected filenames?

Comment: I apologize, it was my fault. It works now.